# How to make an animated stacked bar chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, bar-chart, stacked

I'm trying to create an animated stacked barplot

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

df=pd.DataFrame(
{
    "A":random.sample(range(50,70),6),
    "B":random.sample(range(50,70),6),
    "C":random.sample(range(50,70),6),
    "D":random.sample(range(50,70),6),
    "E":random.sample(range(50,70),6)
}
)


df = df.T
days = np.arange(1,len(df.columns.values) +1)
day = min(days)
x = list(df.index.values)
n = len(days)

def update(new):
    day = days[new]
    y = df[day]
    x = list(df.index.values)

    plt.bar(x,y,bottom = y[new],label = day)
    plt.title(f"Day: {day}")

    plt.legend()

    for x,y in zip(x,y):
        plt.text(x,y,str(y) + "%",ha="center",va="bottom")

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,7))
animate = FuncAnimation(fig,update,interval = 2000)
animate.save("new_animate.gif",dpi = 100)
```

But the plot does not come out as I want. I am using Python 3.9 on Windows 10 32 bit.

Comment: "Does not come out as I want" is not very informative.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. With "Does not come out as I want", i  intended to say that the bars do not appear stacked.